# Programmatically triggering MSBuild is giving build error for Edit & Continue /ZI property

Tags: c++, debugging, msbuild, msbuild-task, edit-and-continue

I'm simulating custom debugger with Edit and Continue through VSExtension, so during live debug session, I'm programmatically triggering MSBuild ,compile to generate .obj file which I can use.

```
enter code here
        logger.Verbosity = LoggerVerbosity.Detailed;
        MsBuild.Execution.BuildRequestData buildRequest = new MsBuild.Execution.BuildRequestData(projectPath, properties, null, new string[] { "ClCompile" /*target*/ }, null);
        MsBuild.Execution.BuildParameters buildParams = new MsBuild.Execution.BuildParameters()
        {
            DetailedSummary = true, /*false,*/
            Loggers = new List<ILogger>() { logger }
        };

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((Object) =>
        {
        try
        {
            MsBuild.Execution.BuildResult result = MsBuild.Execution.BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(buildParams, buildRequest);
            if (result.OverallResult == MsBuild.Execution.BuildResultCode.Success)
            {
                logger.Write(String.Format("compile succeeded \"{0}\"\n", selectedFiles)); //Test.cpp
            }
        }
        }
```

This works for Project default debug property /Zi, but when I change it to /ZI EDIT and Continue I get build failure error project.IDB file already in use, with suggestion to use /FS.

```
Test.cpp(0): error C1041: cannot open program database 'C:\Project\Debug\vc142.idb'; if multiple CL.EXE write to the same .PDB file, please use /FS
```

even if I set /FS in project properties page it is not resolving programmatic build issue.
[image]

[image]

If I can change debug output path to some other path/set of files in Programmatically invoked MSBuild it will likely resolve, but unable to identify how to set it through MS BuildRequestData and BuildParameters.

I'm passing follwoing properties dictionary to MSBuild Parmeteres

```
        properties.Add("SelectedFiles", DocName);
        properties.Add("BuildProjectReferences", "false");
        properties.Add("SolutionDir", val("$(SolutionDir)"));
        properties.Add("SolutionExt", val("$(SolutionExt)"));
        properties.Add("SolutionName", val("$(SolutionName)"));
        properties.Add("SolutionFileName", val("$(SolutionFileName)"));
        properties.Add("SolutionPath", val("$(SolutionPath)"));
```

Added Note 1:
Going through MSDN found there is VCconfig class using which I can change outputpath and intermediateDirectory, but not sure how to make this work, as MSBuild is one class and VCConfiguration is unrelated different class.

Added Note 2:
Here Idea is during live debug while, I'm halted at breakpoint, using dte, MSBuild etc. programmatically I will compile custom file generate FileName.obj and manually patch exe.
But

1. if use /ZI MSBuild fails with vc142.idb in use error.
2. VS detects EXE is not in synch with Custom File so give Stop Debugging error box.
   [image]
   So may be changing paths for programmatic MSBuild will solve Error 1.

And for Error2 somehow VS detection has to be suprressed to continue debugging.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcconfiguration.intermediatedirectory?view=visualstudiosdk-2019

Comment: Isn't this expected? You say 'live debug session' so probably with 'edit and continue' on the debugger takes a lock on the .pdb, but you're trying to write to that same .pdb. /fs is only for serialising calls for e.g. multi-process compilation.

Comment: stijn, I  understand .pdb and .exe files will be locked in debug session, This is the reason I want to programmatically change output and intermediate directory of MSBUILD instance so that only FileName.obj is genereated at e.g. ./debug/EnC.
And I'm only compiling to generate obj file which I can load and patch manually but build should succeed.

Comment: Apologies, I misread/interpreted 'will likely resolve'. Anyway, first things first: do you have control over the project file (as in: is it yours, can you edit it?)? Because if you don't and this should work for any arbitrary vcxproj then changing OutputPath and whatnot is not usable: you might encounter project files which manually set `ProgramDataBaseFileName` to whatever arbitrary value, not based on OutputPath or IntermediateDirectory. Meaning that your only option is to set `ProgramDataBaseFileName` directly.

Comment: I've full control on Project's .vcxproj file, I'm not seeing any explicit entry in vcxproj file for vc142.idb etc.

Comment: In that case seems easiest to create exactly those entries, like `<ProgramDataBaseFileName>$(OutDir)$(MyPdbOverride).pdb</ProgramDataBaseFileName>` under `<ClCompile>` then supply a default value for the MyPdbOverride property in your vcxproj, but override that when building programmatically.

Comment: Thank you stijn, I 'll try that likely this should solve issue 1. but what can be done for issue 2 i.e. custom file is out of sync with program database
"Edit and Continue : error  : The dependency information for 'test.xyz' in the state (*.idb) file(s) '' is out of sync with the Program Database (*.pdb) file 'C:\Projects\TestProj.pdb' for 'TestProj.exe'. Ensure that the file is compiled with the Enable Minimal Rebuild (/Gm) option."